# Unexpected Hash flattening

Tags: hashmap, raku

I'm looking for explanation why those two data structures are not equal:

```
$ perl6 -e 'use Test; is-deeply [ { a => "b" } ], [ { a => "b" }, ];'
not ok 1 -
# Failed test at -e line 1
# expected: $[{:a("b")},]
#      got: $[:a("b")]
```

Trailing comma in Hashes and Arrays is meaningless just like in P5:

```
$ perl6 -e '[ 1 ].elems.say; [ 1, ].elems.say'
1
1
```

But without it Hash is somehow lost and it gets flattened to array of Pairs:

```
$ perl6 -e '[ { a => "b", c => "d" } ].elems.say;'
2
```

I suspect some Great List Refactor laws apply here but I'd like to get more detailed explanation to understand logic behind this flattening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Trailing comma in Hashes and Arrays is meaningless just like in P5

No, it's not meaningless:

```
(1 ).WHAT.say ; # (Int)
(1,).WHAT.say ; # (List)
```

---

The big simplification in the Great List Refactor was switching to [the single argument rule](https://docs.perl6.org/language/list#Single_Argument_Rule) for iterating features<sup>1</sup>. That is to say, features like a `for` or the array and hash composers (and subscripts) always get a single argument. That is indeed what's going on with your original example.

The single argument may be -- often will be -- a list of values, possibly even a list of lists etc., but the top level list would still then be a single argument to the iterating feature.

If the single argument to an iterating feature does the [Iterable](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable) role (for example lists, arrays, and hashes), then it's iterated. (This is an imprecise formulation; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594328/1077672) to "When does for call the iterator method?" for a more precise one.)

So the key thing to note here about that extra comma is that if the single argument does *not* do the `Iterable` role, such as `1`, then the end result is exactly the same as if the argument were instead a list containing just that one value (i.e. `1,`):

```
.perl.say for {:a("b")}   ; # :a("b")     Iterable Hash was iterated
.perl.say for {:a("b")} , ; # {:a("b")}   Iterable List was iterated
.perl.say for 1           ; # 1           Non Iterable 1 left as is
.perl.say for 1 ,         ; # 1           Iterable List was iterated
```

The typical way "to preserve structure [other than] using trailing comma when single element list is declared" (see comment below), i.e. to 
*stop* a single `Iterable` value being iterated as it normally would, is by *item*-izing it with a `$`:

```
my @t = [ $[ $[ "a" ] ] ];
@t.push: "b";
@t.perl.say; # [[["a"],], "b"]
```

<sup>1</sup> The iteration is used to get values to be passed to some code in the case of a `for`; to get values to become elements of the array/hash being constructed in the case of a composer; to get an indexing slice in the case of a subscript; and so on for other iterating features.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I always thought that GLR introduced only iteration DWIMness - that original structure is preserved but iteration flattens single element lists on the fly. While in fact flattening happens in declaration stage - `my @t = [ [ [ "a" ] ] ]; @t.push: "b"; @t.perl.say` gives `["a", "b"]`. So... there is no other way to preserve structure than using trailing comma when single element list is declared, right?

Comment: If there is one, I'd like to know about it as well  :-)

Comment: @raiph Itemizing feels like a legit way to stop Iterables from being iterated to me.

Comment: (I forgot to mention that) I updated my answer to include Liz++'s suggestion. As another example corresponding to Pawel's comment, `my @t = [ $[ $[ "a" ] ] ]; @t.push: "b"; @t.perl.say` gives `[[["a"],], "b"]`.