# When does for call the iterator method?

Tags: mixins, raku

This question is [in the same ballpark as this other on making blocks iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578740/mixing-roles-into-callables), but seems to reveal a different problem with mixins (or a different misunderstanding of the syntax on my part). What [`Iterable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable) does is to make a data structure effectively iterable, that is, you can create loops by preceding it with `for`.

> Iterable serves as an API for objects that can be iterated with the for construct and related iteration constructs, like hyper operators.

So let's try to put this to practice:

```
 my &logger = -> $event  {
    state %store;
    if ( $event ) {
        %store{ DateTime.new( now ) } = $event;
    } else {
        %store;
    }
}

role Forable does Iterable {
    method iterator(&self:) {
        self( Nil );
    }
}

logger( "One" );
logger( "Two" );

&logger does Forable;

.say for &logger;
```

This simply does not work; `say` is applied to `&logger` as a simple item. However, it works if we change that last sentence to:

```
.say for &logger.iterator;
```

Which I guess that indicates that the role is actually working, and mixed in. Since the type for `&logger` is `Block+{Forable}`, maybe it does not work if Iterable is not mixed in directly. In fact, erasing `does Iterable` from the `Forable` declaration does not affect it in any way. Let's try then this:

```
&logger does (Iterable,Forable);
```

Now the type of `&logger` is revealed as `Block+{Iterable,Forable}`, but still no joy. `iterator` has to be called directly. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When does `for` call the iterator method?

As I understand, if the ([single](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439968/1077672)) argument to an iterating feature is a `Scalar` container, then it uses the value in the container and does not call `.iterator`. Otherwise, it calls `.iterator` on it, evaluating it first if it's an expression or routine call.

---

```
&logger does Forable;
.say for &logger;
```

> This simply does not work; `say` is applied to `&logger` as a simple item.

The `&` is a noun marker (sigil) marking a `Callable` that is inherently a single thing, a single block of code.

More specifically, `&logger` is bound to a `Scalar` container whose type is `Callable`, exactly the same as `$logger` (with a `$` sigil) would be if you wrote `my Callable $logger`:

```
say .WHAT, .VAR, .VAR.WHAT, .VAR.of
for my &logger, my Callable $logger
```

displays:

```
(Callable)Callable(Scalar)(Callable)
(Callable)Callable(Scalar)(Callable)
```

> Since the type for `&logger` is `Block+{Forable}`

That's actually the type of the `Callable` that's *contained in* the `Scalar` container that's bound to `&logger`.

It's *not* the type of the `&logger` container itself, which is a `Scalar`, as shown above.

When given a single argument in the form of a variable, iterating features like `for` look at the variable, not the value contained in the variable, to see if it's `Iterable`. A `Scalar` is not `Iterable`.

> Any idea on how to solve this?

See lizmat's answer for one approach.

Comment: Initially, what I wanted to illustrate was how to add a role to a variable. Your answer provides answer to one of my questions, but in this case logger is not Iterable, but returns an Iterable. Which kinda answers the second one: for calls iterator (in this case, on the hash)  when the variable supplied effectively is effectively iterable. I'll have to take it from there, I guess. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "add a role to a variable.". As you've discovered and [I confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50593692/1077672), if you add any role to a `Scalar` container it stops working.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can.  The basic problem is that `&foo` (the `Callable` object) and `foo()` (calling the `Callable` object) are two very different things.

Feels to me you're trying to add a `method` to a `class`, but you're working with a `Sub`.

You need to mixin the `iterator` method on the return value of `logger`.  As I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to answer the question.

Looking at the *result* that you apparently want to achieve, I came up with this:

```
my %store;
multi sub logger() {
    %store
}
multi sub logger($event) {
    %store{ DateTime.new( now ) } = $event;
}

logger( "One" );
logger( "Two" );

.say for logger;
```

But that doesn't use `role`s at all.  So that may not be what you're going for.

Comment: `Callable` is a role.  `Sub`, `Routine`, `Block`, `Code` are classes.  The `Callable` role serves the purpose of *marking* something as callable (and mixes in some utility methods).  You cannot pun the `Callable` role into a class and have something you can execute.