# "Cannot assign to immutable value" when trying to assign to a string + role

Tags: iterator, mixins, raku

Starting with [the example in the Iterable doc page](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable)

```
role DNA does Iterable {
  method iterator(){ self.comb.iterator }
};

my @a does DNA = 'GAATCC';
.say for @a; # OUTPUT: «G␤A␤A␤T␤C␤C␤»
```

I found it weird it's declared using the `@`, so I changed it to the *natural* way of declaring strings, `$`:

```
my $a does DNA = 'GAATCC';
```

But that fails with a somewhat bewildering "Cannot assign to an immutable value". No need to assign on the spot, so we can do:

```
my $a = 'GAATCC';
$a does DNA;
.say for $a;
```

Which just leaves mixing-in for later. But that just prints the string, without paying any attention to the `Iterable` mixin. Let's call it then explicitly:

```
.say for $a.iterator;
```

it does kinda the same thing as before, only it prints the value of `$a.iterator`, without actually calling the function:

```
<anon|69>.new
```

This looks like [the same thing it's going on in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580476/when-does-for-call-the-iterator-method). Baseline question is I don't understand what role Iterable really does, and what `for` really does and when it is calling `iterator` on some object. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question's title points to a bug. This answer covers the bug and also other implicit and explicit questions you asked.

## Background

> fails with a somewhat bewildering "Cannot assign to an immutable value".

I think that's a bug. Let's start with some code that works:

```
my $a = 42;
say $a;          # 42
say WHAT $a;     # (Int)               type of VALUE currently ASSIGNED to $a
say WHAT VAR $a; # (Scalar)            type of VARIABLE currently BOUND to $a
$a = 42;         # works fine
```

In the `my` declaraton `$a` gets BOUND to a new [`Scalar` container](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Scalar). A `Scalar` container normally hides itself. If you ask `WHAT` type `$a` is, you actually get the type of the value currently ASSIGNED to the Scalar (the value it "contains"). You need `VAR` to access the *container* BOUND to $a. When you assign with `=` to a `Scalar` container you copy the assigned value **into** the container.

```
role foo {}
$a does foo;     # changes the VALUE currently ASSIGNED to $a
                 # (NOT the VARIABLE that is BOUND to $a)
say $a;          # 42                  mixed in `foo` role is invisible
say WHAT $a;     # (Int+{foo})         type of VALUE currently ASSIGNED to $a
say WHAT VAR $a; # (Scalar)            type of VARIABLE currently BOUND to $a
$a = 99; say $a; # 99
```

The `does` mixes the `foo` role into the `42`. You can still assign to $a because it's still bound to a `Scalar`.

Note how these two uses of `does` have very different effects:

```
my $a does foo;  # mixes `foo` into VARIABLE bound to $a
$a does foo;     # mixes `foo` into VALUE assigned to $a
```

## The bug

```
$a.VAR does foo; # changes VARIABLE currently BOUND to $a (and it loses the 42)
say $a;          # Scalar+{foo}.new    VALUE currently ASSIGNED to $a
say WHAT $a;     # (Scalar+{foo})      type of VALUE currently ASSIGNED to $a
say WHAT VAR $a; # (Scalar+{foo})      type of VARIABLE currently BOUND to $a

$a = 'uhoh';     # Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

The `does` mixes the `foo` role into the `Scalar` bound to $a. It seems that a `Scalar` with a mixin no longer successfully functions as a container and the assignment fails.

This currently looks to me like a bug.

```
my $b does foo;  # BINDS mixed in VARIABLE to $b
$b = 'uhoh';     # Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

`my $b does foo` has the same result as `my $b; $b.VAR does foo;` so you get the same problem as above.

## Other things you were confused about

```
my $a = 'GAATCC';
$a does DNA;
.say for $a;
```

> just prints the string, without paying any attention to the `Iterable` mixin.

Because the `$a` VARIABLE is still bound to a `Scalar` (as explained in the **Background** section above), the VALUE that now has a `DNA` role mixed in is irrelevant per [the decision process `for` uses about whether to call its argument's `.iterator` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594328/1077672).

> Let's call it then explicitly ... prints the value of `$a.iterator`, without actually calling the function:

```
.say for $a.iterator;
```

Well it does call your `DNA` role's `.iterator` method. But that has *another* `.iterator` call at the end of the `self.comb` returned by your `DNA` role's `iterator` method so you're `.say`ing that secondary `.iterator`.

## Solutions that work today

I think Brad's answer nicely covers most of your options.

And I think your nice [`does DNA` gist](https://github.com/JJ/my-perl6-examples/blob/master/does-dna.p6) is as good as it gets with today's P6 if you want to use the `$` sigil.

## A solution that might one day work

In an ideal world all the sweetness in the P6 design would be fully realized in `6.c` and the Rakudo compiler implementation of Perl 6. Perhaps that would include the ability to write this and get what you want:

```
class DNA is Scalar does Iterable { ... }
my $a is DNA = 'GAATCC';
.say for $a;
```

The `...` code would be about the same as what you have in your gist except that the `DNA` class would be a scalar container, and so the `new` method would instead be a `STORE` method or similar that would assign the passed value to a `$!value` attribute or some such when a value was assigned to the container using `=`.

But instead, you get:

```
is trait on $-sigil variable not yet implemented. Sorry.
```

So the closest you can get today to the ideal of `= 'string'` to change `$a` is to bind using `:= DNA.new('string')` as you did in your gist.

Note that you *can* bind arbitrary composite containers to `@` and `%` sigil variables. So you can see how things are supposed to eventually work.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this line does what you think it does:

```perl6
my @a does DNA = 'GAATCC';
```

It is the same as:

```perl6
my @a := [ 'GAATCC', ];
@a does DNA;
```

Basically the `.comb` call coerces the array into a Str, and splits that into characters.

---

If you instead did this:

```perl6
my @a = 'GAATCC' but DNA;
```

Which is basically the same as

```perl6
my @a := Seq.new(('GAATCC' but DNA).iterator).Array;
```

Note that `@` variables store `Positional` values not `Iterable` values.

---

The thing you want is

```perl6
my $a = 'GAATCC' but DNA;

$a.map: &say;
```

---

If you want to be able to use `for` you can't use a variable with a `$` sigil

```perl6
my \a = 'GAATCC' but DNA;

.say for a;
```

---

You may want to add `Seq` `list` `List` etc methods to `DNA`.

```perl6
role DNA does Iterable {
  method iterator(){
    self.comb.iterator
  }
  method Seq(){
    Seq.new: self.iterator
  }
  method list(){
    # self.Seq.list
    List.from-iterator: self.iterator
  }
}

my $a = 'GAATCC' but DNA;
.say for @$a;
```

Comment: Why can't you use for with a variable with a `$` sigil?

Comment: @jjmerelo It is marked as being an `item` (singular).

Comment: I'm using it [here with the sigil](https://github.com/JJ/my-perl6-examples/blob/master/does-dna.p6) and not a problem.

Comment: @jjmerelo I think that's because you created a new class, rather than deriving from `Str`. I have yet to figure out how to get it to work that way. I assume there is some method that I have to override.