# Assigning a value to the attribute of a mixed-in role

Tags: mixins, raku

I'm trying to work an example that uses the [`Enumeration` role in Perl 6](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/5a6ff4073deecfaf0d7d90a841c826eb003c0ac2/src/core/Enumeration.pm6) (as part of fixing doc issue [Enumeration role is not documented](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1555)). I came up with this simple example:

```perl6
class DNA does Enumeration {
    my $DNAindex = 0;
    my %pairings = %( A => "T",
                      T => "A",
                      C => "G",
                      G => "T" );

    method new( $base-pair where "A" | "C" | "G" | "T" )  {
        self.bless( key => $base-pair,
                    value => %pairings{$base-pair},
                    index => 33);
    }

    multi method gist(::?CLASS:D:) {
        return "$!key -> $!value with $!index";
    }

}

for <A C G T>.roll( 16 ) -> $letter {
    my DNA $base = DNA.new( $letter );
    say "Pairs ", $base.pair,  " with ", $base.gist;
}
```

Theoretically, `Enumeration` `has` `$!index`, and with `index => 33` I try to assign a value to it; however, all it returns is something like

```perl6
 Pairs T => A with T -> A with 0
```

Any other way to assign a value to $!index directly, and I get [the "cannot assign to an immutable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590224/cannot-assign-to-immutable-value-when-trying-to-assign-to-a-string-role) I got in another question. That might be a bug, according to [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50593692/1077672); in that case, I'd like to know if there's some workaround to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug [Cannot change native role attribute from consuming class](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=126120) (nothing to do with the one mentioned in the answer you linked).

I don't know of a workaround.