# Mixing-in roles in traits apparently not working

Tags: traits, raku

This example is taken [from `roast`](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/S14-traits/variables.t), although it's been there for 8 years:

```
role doc { has $.doc is rw }

multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable $a, :$docced!) {
    $a does doc.new(doc => $docced);
}

my $dog is docced('barks');
say $dog.VAR;
```

This returns `Any`, without any kind of role mixed in. There's apparently no way to get to the "doc" part, although the trait does not error. Any idea?

Comment: I think JJ is really mostly interested in the mixing in mechanism. But for those interested in other ways to do it, [attaching `Pod` to declarators](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pod#Declarator_blocks) (which can then be retrieved via [`.WHY`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/WHY)) is supposed to work for attaching doc to variables. That said implementation of the `Pod` design is still a work in progress and it seems to only work for parameters at the moment, eg. `my &sub = -> ␤ $bar #= hi ␤ {} ␤ say &sub.signature.params[0].WHY; # hi`, and the ␤s in that code are (imo far too) important.

Comment: (Btw, the [`Variables` doc page](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Variable) says "The runtime class of a variable is `Scalar`." *Some* variables in P6 are bound to `Scalar`s, but some are instead bound to scalars -- lowercase 's' -- such as `42` and many others to `Array`s, `Hash`s etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer builds on @guifa's answer and JJ's comment.)

The idiom to use in variable traits is essentially `$var.var.VAR`.

While that sounds fun when said aloud it also seems crazy. It isn't, but it demands explanation at the very least and *perhaps* some sort of cognitive/syntactic relief.

Here's the brief version of how to make some sense of it:

- `$var` makes sense as the name of the trait parameter because it's bound to a [`Variable`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Variable), a *compiler's-eye* view of a variable.
- `.var` is needed to access the *user's-eye* view of a variable given the compiler's-eye view.
- If the variable is a `Scalar` then a `.VAR` is needed *as well* to get the variable rather than the value it contains. (It does no harm if it isn't a `Scalar`.)

## Some relief?

I'll explain the above in more detail in a mo, but first, what about some relief?

Perhaps we could introduce a new `Variable` method that does `.var.VAR`. But imo this would be a mistake unless the name for the method is so good it essentially eliminates the need for the `$var.var.VAR` incantation explanation that follows in the next section of this answer.

But I doubt such a name exists. Every name I've come up with makes matters worse in some way. And even if we came up with the perfect name, it would still barely be worth it at best.

I was struck by the complexity of your original example. There's an `is` trait that calls a `does` trait. So perhaps there's call for a routine that abstracts both that complexity and the `$var.var.VAR`. But there are existing ways to reduce that double trait complexity anyway, eg:

```
role doc[$doc] { has $.doc is rw = $doc}
my $dog does doc['barks'];
say $dog.doc; # barks
```

## A longer explanation of `$var.var.VAR`

> But `$v` is already a variable. Why so many `var` and `VAR`s?

Indeed. `$v` is bound to an instance of the `Variable` class. Isn't that enough?

No, because a `Variable`:

- Is for storing metadata *about* a variable *while it's being compiled*. (Perhaps it should have been called `Metadata-About-A-Variable-Being-Compiled`? Just kidding. `Variable` looks nice in trait signatures and changing its name wouldn't stop us needing to use and explain the `$var.var.VAR` idiom anyway.)
- Is not the droid we are looking for. We want a *user's-eye view* of the variable. One that's been declared and compiled and is then being used as part of user code. (For example, `$dog` in the line `say $dog...`. Even if it were `BEGIN say $dog...`, so it ran at compile-time, `$dog` would *still* refer to a symbol that's bound to a user's-eye view container or value. It would not refer to the `Variable` instance that's only the *compiler's-eye view* of data *related* to the variable.)
- Makes life easier for the compiler and those writing traits. But it requires that a trait writer accesses the user's-eye view of the variable to access or alter the user's-eye view. The `.var` attribute of the `Variable` stores that user's-eye view. (I note the roast test has a `.container` attribute that you omitted. That's clearly now been renamed `.var`. My guess is that that's because a variable may be bound to an immutable value rather than a container so the name `.container` was considered misleading.)

## So, how do we arrive at `$var.var.VAR`?

Let's start with a variant of your original code and then move forward. I'll switch from `$dog` to `@dog` and drop the `.VAR` from the `say` line:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable $a, :$docced!) {
  $a does role { has $.doc = $docced }
}

my @dog is docced('barks');
say @dog.doc; # No such method 'doc' for invocant of type 'Array'
```

This *almost* works. One tiny change and it works:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable $a, :$docced!) {
  $a.var does role { has $.doc = $docced }
}

my @dog is docced('barks');
say @dog.doc; # barks
```

All I've done is add a `.var` to the `... does role ...` line. In your original, that line is modifying *the compiler's-eye view* of the variable, i.e. the `Variable` object bound to `$a`. It doesn't modify the user's-eye view of the variable, i.e. the `Array` bound to `@dog`.

As far as I know everything now works correctly for plural containers like arrays and hashes:

```
@dog[1] = 42;
say @dog;     # [(Any) 42]
say @dog.doc; # barks
```

But when we try it with a `Scalar` variable:

```
my $dog is docced('barks');
```

we get:

```
Cannot use 'does' operator on a type object Any.
```

This is because the `.var` returns whatever it is that the user's-eye view variable usually returns. With an `Array` you get the `Array`. But with a `Scalar` you get the value the `Scalar` contains. (This is a fundamental aspect of P6. It works great but you have to know it in these sorts of scenarios.)

So to get this to *appear* to work again we have to add a couple `.VAR`'s as well. For anything other than a `Scalar` a `.VAR` is a "no op" so it does no harm to cases other than a `Scalar` to add it:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable $a, :$docced!) {
  $a.var.VAR does role { has $.doc = $docced }
}
```

And now the `Scalar` case also appears to work:

```
my $dog is docced('barks');
say $dog.VAR.doc; # barks
```

(I've had to reintroduce the `.VAR` in the `say` line for the same reason I had to add it to the `$a.var.VAR ...` line.)

If all were well that would be the end of this answer.

## A bug

But something is broken. If we'd attempted to initialize the `Scalar` variable:

```
my $dog is docced('barks') = 42;
```

we'd see:

```
Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

As @guifa noted, and [I stumbled on a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50593692/1077672):

> It seems that a `Scalar` with a mixin no longer successfully functions as a container and the assignment fails. This currently looks to me like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Not a satisfactory answer but maybe you can progress from it

```
role doc { 
  has $.doc is rw;
}

multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable:D $v, :$docced!) {
  $v.var.VAR does doc;
  $v.var.VAR.doc = $docced;
}

say $dog;            # ↪︎ Scalar+{doc}.new(doc => "barks")
say $dog.doc;        # ↪︎ barks
$dog.doc = 'woofs';  #
say $dog;            # ↪︎ Scalar+{doc}.new(doc => "woofs")
```

Unfortunately, there is something off with this, and applying the trait seems to cause the variable to become immutable.